# How do I know if a pipe is a gas pipe

Tags: electrical, plumbing, gas

Hi we have a pipe where we want to take the wall out and put French doors in but are unsure what the pipe is and whether we are able to move it or get rid of it

Comment: In most construction a water pipe is copper or plastic.  Gas is usually black iron pipe.  A picture would be helpful.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. We'll need more info to help you. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Be careful as in some locations the incoming water pipe is steel... so check for your location - is there a meter outside - gas or water?

Comment: What country are you in? Different countries have different colour schemes.
Can you share some more information about where the pipe is in relation to the gas meter and any gas burning appliances. 

My rule of thumb is "if in doubt, contract out"

Comment: Have added a pic

Comment: We are in Essex uk

Comment: Pipe is under window and gas meter is in opposite corner of room

Comment: What pic where?

Comment: put your ear against the pipe and have someone turn a tap in the kitchen on and off several times ... you may be able to hear the water rushing through the pipes

Comment: I suggest basics; follow to where it starts or ends . You will be very disappointed when you cut it to find either gas or water ( or even electricity).

Comment: Anything can be moved is cost is not an issue.